# Can't edit mesh in Edit Mode!

Tags: modeling

This is urgent. I'm working on a massive file and I cannot share the blend file.

I can't edit anything at all in Edit mode. I click "G" to move a vertex, face or edge, and nothing moves. Absolutely nothing. I'm working on an important project and I need to have this done today.

I have no idea what happened, I might've clicked something but Blender tell me nothing. I've never seen this and I can't fix it.

Please, any help is welcomed, this is very urgent!

Comment: You say that this file is huge? Can you share a screenshot or a small video?

Comment: What mode are you in. Do the verts go orange when selected?

Comment: @Sanbaldo He has stated that the file is way too large for him to share.

Comment: Have you made sure that you selected selection pointer?
Normally top left bar, it is a cursor with an orange circle around it. When you select it it should fix it